# How to change section numbering formatting

Tags: sectioning

I’m looking for a way (or a package) to change or control the formatting of the **numbers** of a section. By formatting, I mean the fonts and the like, not the formatting of the number

As far as I can see, the only way seems to redefine the `@sect` command, for example. But I’d prefer to avoid this: as you can see, I’m not a TeX expert.

Comment: There are the packages `sectsty` and `titlesec`. The package `titlesec` is more complicated then `sectsty`, but can do more. If I understand your question correctly, I think `sectsty` would be sufficient for you.

Comment: Could you be more precise about what changes you have in mind? Surely `\@sect` is not the macro to act on, anyway.

Comment: Which class are you using? There are some classes with predefined styles, see e.g. ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/info/MemoirChapStyles/MemoirChapStyles.pdf

Comment: @egreg I’d like to change, say, the typeface of the number.

Comment: @PietvanOostrum Thanks for the suggestions. I’ll try them out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For extensive changes to the sectional titles, `titlesec` is the package to go. For less extensive changes, you can go with internals.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \@nameuse{additional@cntformat#1}%
  {\@nameuse{the#1}}%
  \endgroup
  \quad
}
\newcommand{\setformat}[2]{%
  \@namedef{additional@cntformat#1}{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\setformat{section}{\itshape}
\setformat{subsection}{\normalfont}
\setformat{subsubsection}{\fbox}

\begin{document}

\section{Example of section}

\subsection{Example of subsection}

\subsubsection{Example of subsubsection}

\end{document}
```

The last token in the second argument to `\setformat` can take an argument, like in the example for `\subsubsection`.

[image]